# `%` character in the end of file when use File.write or IO.write

Tags: elixir, zsh

After I execute the following code:

```
File.touch("testfile")
file = File.open!("testfile", [:write, :utf8])
IO.write(file, "My pretty text")
```

I see extra `%` character when reading a file in os terminal.
But when I open a file with a text editor I can't see this character.
Can someone explain for me why I see this character?

[image]

Comment: I guess it is related to your zsh theme. Try using bash only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is zsh telling you that you have no newline character at the end of the output.

I don't use zsh, but you can probably reproduce it with `echo -n "test"`

`IO.write(file, "My pretty text\n")` probably won't give you the `%`.